# ajax page load and sliding divs across page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, slide

I'm using AJAX to load pages into a div `main_content` wrapped in div `main`. I.e., only the content in the `main_content` div changes. This is done with a regular javascript function. The site has a static menu bar and about 10-15 pages. What I want to do is when the `loadPage()` function is called, slide the new page in from the left and the current (soon-to-be OLD) page out to the right, like a continuous scroll. I don't necessarily want to "preload" all the pages behind the scenes. I have searched and searched and cannot find anything that will help me do this exact thing. I'd appreciate any help anyone can give me. I'd really prefer not to use jQuery if it is possible.

Comment: please put ur code in jsfiddle so that we can fix for u

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eo8zp1gv/

Comment: Again, what I am wanting to do is VISIBLY move the current page out to the right and off the screen while the new page VISIBLY slides in from the left.